# AlertDialog Builder inside holder.itemView.setOnClickListener onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I am trying to delete an item from the database when the user clicks on the RecyclerView item a Confirmation Dialog opens and if the user press yes then it will delete the item from firebase.

I think the problem is the alert dialogue is not showing in the app due to the context as such what should I enter in the context to display the alertDialog on screen

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final DishViewHolderModify holder, int position) {

    final Dish dish = dishList.get(position);
    holder.textViewDishName.setText(dish.getmName());
    Picasso.get().load(dish.getmImageUrl()).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(holder.imageViewDishImage, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Picasso.get().load(dish.getmImageUrl()).into(holder.imageViewDishImage);
        }
    });
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Click Happen","Yes");
            final String dishName = holder.textViewDishName.getText().toString();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()) // problem over here
            .setTitle("Delete Dish")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_forever_black_24dp)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    letsDeleteDish(dishName);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No",null);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you have not called `show()` on your `AlertDialog.Builder` instance. I don't see anything wrong with your `Context` argument.

This is the last line of the builder:

> ```
> }).setNegativeButton("No",null);
> ```

Probably this should look like this instead:

```
}).setNegativeButton("No",null)
.show();
```